# nvidia-settings overclocking; How do you know the offset to use?

Tags: nvidia

To overclock/underclock nvidia card I see this:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=-500
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=1000
```

The example GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3] didn't work for me, another howto showed the same command but with offset GPUGraphicsClockOffset[1]. That didn't work either, so I tried GPUGraphicsClockOffset[2], then GPUGraphicsClockOffset[4] which finally worked.

Where is it described which offset to use?

This is what worked for me:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[4]=-500 
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:1]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[4]=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need an **xorg.conf**, and make sure it includes:

```
Option "Coolbits" "28"
```

On the Screen section.

Then you can use nvidia-settings to check out what options you can define. Look them up on the PowerMizer tab.

What video card do you have? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).